# how to add value this MAX number

Tags: php, mysql

This is my `SQL` query.

```
$max_Number = DBGet(DBQuery("SELECT MAX(student_id) FROM students"));
```

When I print as array in `PHP`. This array appear like this. `print_r($max_Number);`

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [MAX(STUDENT_ID)] => 4436 ) )
```

**I want add 1 for the `4436` this value in php. how to do that.please help me**

Comment: $max_Number[1][MAX(STUDENT_ID)] = $max_Number[1][MAX(STUDENT_ID)] + 1 or add to query.

Comment: how to add this `$max_Number` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1 in a query:

```
SELECT MAX(student_id) + 1 as `max` FROM students
```

Though I don't know why you need to increment `student_id`, but if your case is to **add new item with the next id** - you're doing it **wrong**. Instead - set `student_id` as **AUTOINCREMENT**.

Comment: Then how to `echo` this `max` number.

Comment: `print_r($max_Number);` and see what you have there.

Comment: `$max_Number = DBGet(DBQuery("SELECT MAX(student_id)+1 as MAX FROM students"));$cur_auto_id = ['MAX(student_id)'];echo $cur_auto_id;` I did like this, I need show only value.this is not working properly.

Comment: I repeat: `print_r($max_Number);`, what do you see?

Comment: `Array ( [1] => Array ( [MAX] => 4437 ) )` I can see like this. Now, i want `echo` this `4437` value.

Comment: If you don't know how to access array values - __open a manual__. In your case it is `$max_Number[1]['MAX']`

Comment: Thank you soo much.